How to access web app in internal network on ubuntu
A web application is running on ubuntu machine on port 7777.
I am trying to access this web app in internal network.
I have tried to open port using:
sudo ufw allow 7777/tcp

and I get relevant status
 To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----                      
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
7777                       ALLOW       Anywhere                   
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
7777 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)   

still I can not reach the app through internal network.
I also changed this config net.ipv4.ip_forward=1.
What can be done to share localhost web apps through internal network.
p.s. ssh works fine. Host machine can connect virtual linux through ssh.

You might try opening all ports to a specific server: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-open-http-port-80-and-https-port-443-with-ufw, e.g. sudo ufw allow in "Nginx Full" See also https://serverfault.com/questions/422896/how-to-open-udp-port-7777-from-iptables-firewall-on-ubuntu-11-04,

Is your web app listening on port 7777 on all IP addresses, or only on a loopback IP address?

Doublecheck that your application is actually listening on the port it should be. In the linux terminal type ss -tlpn | grep 7777. You may need to run the command as root (sudo) to see the process names associated with the port.
